# Batch files : How to leave the console window open

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two batch files, one of them executes another, i.e.

1. "My Batch File" > 2. "Some Other Batch File"

I've created a shortcut of the first batch file and edited its properties to call its in following way.

```
cmd.exe /k "<SomePath>\<My Batch File>.bat" & pause
```

**What i want to do**
I want the console window to be open after the execution of the batch file is over. Now it just closes, tried to play around the cmd flags, no result.

Platform : Windows7

---

**UPDATE 1**

Modified the structure, the simple example like this does not work as well,
Only one batch file i.e. there is no the 2. "Some Other Batch File"
The only batch file contains smth like this

```
start /B /LOW /WAIT make package
cmd /K
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

The same shortcut which is invoked from Explorer does not close the console window.
**But the console window closes when the shortcut is invoked from the pinned item on taskbar**

Any ideas how to keep the console window open?

Comment: I presume you want the `My Batch File` to stick around?

Comment: "Hot to leave the console window of a batch file open" is asked and answered way more clearly here: http://superuser.com/questions/175515/is-there-a-way-in-windows-7-to-create-a-shortcut-to-a-command-line-console-app

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If that is really all the batch file is doing, remove the `cmd /K` and add `PAUSE`.

```
start /B /LOW /WAIT make package
PAUSE
```

Then, just point your shortcut to `"My Batch File.bat"`...no need to run it with `CMD /K`.

## UPDATE

Ah, some new info...you're trying to do it from a pinned shortcut on the taskbar.

I found this, [Adding Batch Files to Windows 7 Taskbar like the Vista/XP Quick Launch](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/a44e74a1-20cd-4924-8f2b-3e6b688f1ad7), with the relevant part below.

> 1. First, pin a shortcut for `CMD.EXE` to the taskbar by hitting the start button, then type "cmd" in the search box, right-click the result and chose "Pin to Taskbar".
> 2. Right-click the shortcut on the taskbar.
> 3. You will see a list that includes "*Command Prompt*" and "*Unpin this program from the taskbar*".
> 4. Right-click the icon for `CMD.EXE` and select `Properties`.
> 5. In the box for Target, go to the end of `"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe"` and type `" /C "` and the path and name
>      of the batch file.

For your purposes, you can either:

1. Use `/C` and put a `PAUSE` at the end of your batch file.

   **OR**
2. Change the command line to use `/K` and remove the `PAUSE` from your batch file.

Comment: I've already done it, basically my question is not how to call anohter batch file...

Comment: Then we need to see the contents of both batch files.

Comment: Please see the udpated question

Comment: The same issue, replacing CMD /K does not work. Why the consolse window does not close if the shortcut is invoked from Explorer ?

Answer (score 15):

The problem is here:

```
cmd.exe /k "<SomePath>\<My Batch File>.bat" & pause
```

Take a look what are you doing:

1. (cmd /K) Start **a NEW** cmd instance.
2. (& pause) Pause **the CURRENT** cmd instance.

How to resolve it? well,using the correct syntax, enclosing the argument for the new CMD instance:

```
cmd.exe /k ""<SomePath>\<My Batch File>.bat" & pause"
```

Answer (score 6):

I just written last line as **Pause** it worked fine with both .bat and .cmd.
It will display message also as 'Press any key to continue'.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Should be the top voted.

Answer (score 5):

In the last line of the batch file that you want to keep open put a

`pause >nul`

Comment: Sounds like it is closing early then, maybe an error in the script. Try opening a cmd prompt and running it from there, then you can see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 3):

For leaving the console window open you only have to add to the last command line in the batch file:

```
' & pause'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just put a [`pause` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490965.aspx) in the last line of your batch file:

```
@echo off
echo Hey, I'm just doing some work for you.
pause
```

Will give you something like this as output:

> Hey, I'm just doing some work for you.
>
> Press any key to continue ...

**Note:** Using the @echo prevents to output the command before the output is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem Just use "pause" at the end of the batch file.
...
......
.......
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

put at the end it will reopen your console

```
start cmd
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, the user wants to keep the window open, not reopen an old one.

Answer (score -5):

I just press enter and type Pause and it works fine