# Use batch file to launch ssdeep with file arguments

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I am attempting to use a looping batch file to launch the CMD app ssdeep and pass a file argument to it, then keep the ssdeep window open to copy a chunk of output to the clipboard  I have the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
:start
SET /p filetohash= What file would you like to fuzzy hash? 
START C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ssdeep-2.10\ssdeep-2.10\ssdeep.exe %filetohash%
PAUSE
goto start
```

This allows me to run the batch file, which I can then drag and drop a file to hash into the CMD window.  Upon hitting return, the ssdeep CMD window appears for the moment it takes to hash the file, then closes.  This leaves me with the 1st window generated by the batch file, that is requesting a key press.

I want to have the 2nd CMD window stay open so I can copy the hash out.  Similar to the PAUSE I used in the batch file, but I need it to apply to the 2nd CMD window created.

I'm not exactly sure how to search for this information.  I have searched info on batch files.  I used these resources to get thus far:

https://superuser.com/questions/582095/how-to-create-a-batch-file-that-will-run-cmd-and-a-exe-with-parameters

and

[Batch files : How to leave the console window open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746177/batch-files-how-to-leave-the-console-window-open)

Thanks in advance,

PTW-105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the /b switch to the start command - see if that does what you need (leave the pause in).

```
start "" /b C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ssdeep-2.10\ssdeep-2.10\ssdeep.exe %filetohash%
```

The empty double quotes protect the start command if you ever add quoted items in the commands.

Try this command to create `hash.txt` on your desktop - remove the `pause` - it should contain the information if it gets printed to STDOUT.  It can be parsed to extract just the hash: if you add that information to your question it should be in a format that we can read and see how to parse it.

```
start "" /b C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ssdeep-2.10\ssdeep-2.10\ssdeep.exe %filetohash% >"%userprofile%\desktop\hash.txt"
```

Comment: This will work.  To better learn for next time, is there a way to make it cleaner?  I'm guessing the /b switch tells the start command to load the results in the current window?

The output looks like this now:

What file would you like to fuzzy hash? C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ACM\acm\addons\FHQ
_Accessories_v1.2.7z
Press any key to continue . . . ssdeep,1.1--blocksize:hash:hash,filename
393216:ImlppcDhQ7qSB9rr1RwSc8pIwMSAx4A7CyCCAlRVEznjrI3OrtBEblXevxumZEnB:ImlrVX1R
Dcvvx7CLC2/Enf25XUxjMCc,"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\ACM\acm\addons\FHQ_Accessories_v1
.2.7z"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm trying not to export the file to disk at this point.  The "" /b has fixed the my issue and made this work functionally.  I appreciate your time.