# Keep ruby interpreter up after execution

Tags: ruby, debugging

I am a beginner to Ruby and have noticed that whenever I write a script in Notepad and then execute it, it exits straight away so I don't have time to read the output. I have added `input = gets.chomp!` to keep it open, it worked once though now not so.

How do I keep the interpreter up after I have executed my script?

This is my code, I am using Windows.

```
require 'pry'
index = 0
File.open("....txt").each {|x| puts x}
#puts index
binding.pry
```

Thanks for all your help guys, it turns out gets.chomp! works now, my problem was that the file was not text but html. Sorry for all the hassle.

Comment: Possibly like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746177/batch-files-how-to-leave-the-console-window-open

Comment: avoid the `chomp!` until you understand what it is doing.  It won't cause problems in this case, but using it in other ways you may be surprised.  Simply use the `chomp` method without the bang.

Comment: Were you able to solve this matter?

Comment: yes though since can't answer my own question, can't mark as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Open console.
Run your file(type `ruby file.rb`)

Or you can make simple bat file that contains:

```
ruby yourfile.rb
pause
```

Name it with `.bat` extension and run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
irb -r your_file_path
```

It will open your file and execute it before opening irb, so all classes you defined are available to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry).

AFAIK you are trying to do the same thing we all do when debugging and inspecting state.

Add

```
binding.pry
```

somewhere in your code.  The execution will stop there an you can inspect the state at that point.  You could add it at the end of a file, to see what's happened after it's done executing.

You can add as many as you want, and you will get a *breakpoint* at each one.  Types `exit` to leave and go to the next breakpoint, or finish executing.  You can type in standard ruby code at the Pry console.

Just remember to add

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pry'
```

to the start, somewhere, to lead the gem.  You will need to install the gem first with

```
gem install pry
```

which you'll type into the bash command line, not in a ruby console or script file.  If you're on a PC then I don't know how to tell you to install gems.  You should learn, though.

Pry is considered by many to be the best way to debug ruby code.

Comment: It didn't work, this is my code [code]require 'pry'
index = 0
File.open(".....txt").each {|x| puts x}
#puts index
binding.pry[/code]

Comment: Try my modified answer.  Also, Those [code] brackets won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try your code from inside IRB instead. Just run 'irb' from inside your terminal.   The `gets.chomp` line should keep your interpreter up since that waits for user input.

If you did not use `puts` or `p` in your code, then output from your Ruby code won't be displayed in your terminal. You have to do something like this in your code.

`puts "Hello world!"`

The argument you pass to `puts` or `p` gets printed in the terminal. Code like below won't get printed to the terminal:

`1 + 1`

That's probably why you don't see your code's output.

Comment: I have used puts. Would irb be best when making large scipts?

Comment: IRB is best used for short scripts. You'd usually go on IRB to quickly test your own scripts. It's great for immediate feedback.