# Running a simple Console App in Dnx/AspNet5 and will not run outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core, dnx

I've written a small simple console app as a AspNet5 Console Package

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Running this through debug in Visual Studio and I get a command window with Hello World written in.  However when I compile this with project properties "Produce outputs on build" I get an artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app directory produced with the following output
[image]

and a dnx46 directory with
[image]

Contents of the .cmd file in the app directory is

```
@dnx --appbase "%~dp0." Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost ConsoleApp1 %*
```

Contents of the project.json file is the following

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleApp1 Console Application",
  "authors": [
    "Doug"
  ],
  "tags": [
    ""
  ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ConsoleApp1": "1.0.0"
  },
  "commands": {
    "ConsoleApp1": "ConsoleApp1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx46": {
      "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
    }
  },
  "entryPoint": "ConsoleApp1",
  "loadable": false
}
```

Double clicking the cmd file won't run the program.  I put in the ReadLine() code to pause the app on run to see what the output would be, but I see it flash then go away.  I've also tried running it from the app directory in powershell using the following command "dnx ConsoleApp1" but it won't run.  This is just a simple console application and shouldn't be this hard to run but I can't seem to get it to run outside of the visual studio environment.  What am I doing wrong????

**Update 1**
I got this to run executing from the directory of the src, but I can't seem to run the outputs in the same fashion from the artifacts directory.  Any ideas???

```
PS C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1> dnx run
Hello world
```

Just as an FYI here is my dnvm list output
[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Below is the output if I change to the directory of the ".cmd" file and try executing it manually in an open window which is why it just terminates and closes...  due to the contents of the .cmd file I figured this at the very least would work... I will try the dnu publish shortly.  If the publish works then what is the point of the .cmd files produced in the artifacts directory.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, so I ran the dnu publish command from the directory that contains the project source files.  The output is below.

[image]

The resulting ".cmd" file highlighted in the directory structure was double clicked and the cmd.exe window appeared with the correct output.  The directory structure and output are below.
[image]

However this made me curious... when I run the same dnu publish command in the artifacts directory produced by the compile and "Produce build outputs" option checked and the resulting .cmd file would not execute the console program???  What is the difference between the output in the artifacts directory and the files in program source that allow everything to be pulled together to execute.

PS...  this seems like ALOT of work just to get a console program to run outside of visual studio!  Is this the intent of DNX? No exe's? just curious

**UPDATE 4**
I ran the following in the directory for the output artifacts... the result was still no runable version of the program in the artifacts directory but the output files look almost identical to that of what was in the /src directory bin.

I apologize for not taking a screen shot but my screen wasn't big enough to hold everything at once.

```
PS C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app> dnu restore
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\project.json
Writing lock file C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 123ms elapsed

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\Doug\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config

Feeds used:
    https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

PS C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app> dnu publish --runtime active --no-source
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

Copying to output path C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\bin\output
Using Project dependency app 1.0.0 for DNX,Version=v4.6
  Packing nupkg from Project dependency app
    Source C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\project.json
    Target C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\bin\output\approot\packages\app\1.0.0

Building app for DNX,Version=v4.6
  Using Project dependency app 1.0.0
    Source: C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\project.json

  Using Project dependency ConsoleApp1 1.0.0
    Source: C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\project.json

  Using Assembly dependency fx/mscorlib 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/System 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/System.Core 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Microsoft.CSharp.dll

dnu : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
At line:1 char:1
+ dnu publish --runtime active --no-source
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (error CS5001: P... an entry point:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


Build failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.3519605
Total build time elapsed: 00:00:00.3550713
Total projects built: 1

Using Project dependency ConsoleApp1 1.0.0 for DNX,Version=v4.6
  Packing nupkg from Project dependency ConsoleApp1
    Source C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\project.json
    Target C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\bin\output\approot\packages\ConsoleApp1\1.0.0

Building ConsoleApp1 for DNX,Version=v4.6
  Using Project dependency ConsoleApp1 1.0.0
    Source: C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\project.json

  Using Assembly dependency fx/mscorlib 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/System 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/System.Core 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0
    Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Exported application command: ConsoleApp1
ConsoleApp1 -> C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.1.0.0.nupkg
ConsoleApp1 -> C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.2780556
Total build time elapsed: 00:00:00.2790409
Total projects built: 1
Adding NuGet package C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.1.0.0.nupkg to C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visua
l Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app\bin\output\approot\packages
Installing ConsoleApp1.1.0.0
Add complete, 46ms elapsed
Removing C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.1.0.0.nupkg
Removing C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg

Bundling runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1
Time elapsed 00:00:01.1140479

PS C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\artifacts\bin\ConsoleApp1\Debug\app>
```

Here was the directory output resulting in running the command dnu publish in the artifacts directory... the output was the same but the .cmd file wouldn't run

[image]

Can you tell me the difference between running against the /src directory of the project vs the /artifacts directory on produce outputs?

PS: sorry for such a long post, just really trying to wrap my head around this DNX stuff!  And again thanks for your help

Comment: run `dnvm list` to know what is the runtime version you use. Open a command promt and go to your source code : `cd C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\ConsoleApp1`. And run `dnx ConsoleApp1`. And share outputs.

Comment: Read the update.  I got it to run that way.  From the src directory.  This directory however contains the source code.  I'm wondering why I can't run from the artifacts directory where the build output is placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you listing multiple problems, I'm going to address them individually.

> Double clicking the cmd file won't run the program. I put in the ReadLine() code to pause the app on run to see what the output would be, but I see it flash then go away.

That's expected. The cmd file launches the application in a new console and when the process terminates, the console closes.

You have a few options:

1. Just like you did, add a ReadLine at the end of the program.
2. Run the cmd file from a console.
3. Keep the console open after run by following the instructions in this question [Batch files : How to leave the console window open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746177/batch-files-how-to-leave-the-console-window-open)

> Update 1 I got this to run executing from the directory of the src, but I can't seem to run the outputs in the same fashion from the artifacts directory. Any ideas???

"Produce outputs on build" doesn't produce runnable executables (yes, it's confusing), but nuget packages.

So, in the dnx world:

1. If you produce outputs on build, that's the equivalent of running `dnu pack`.
2. If you want to create a folder that has a runnable app, you have to run `dnu publish` (or Publish from VS). Depending on what arguments you pass, you will get a folder that has the runnable app, its dependencies and, optionally, the runtime.

   So, a self contained published app can be produced with:

   ```
   dnu publish --runtime <runtime name or "active"> --no-source
   ```

   The `--no-source` argument will precompile the projects for which you have sources (this is the closest you'll get to a classic C# app). Without that argument, the sources will be compile on the fly every time the app starts.

   The default output of the publish command is under `bin\output`

Comment: I have a ReadLine at the end of the program... you can see it at the end of  Main() in the console app contents I have in the question.  I tried running the ConsoleApp1.cmd from within a already open command prompt and it won't run.  Since it's a ".cmd" file I thought you could just double click it to run the application since no .exe file was produced in the output files.  I will try the dnu publish after a bit and let you know, thanks for all the info!

Comment: Victor,  I just tried a few things that you told me, one worked but a few other things didn't... not sure what the difference is between dnu publish on /artifacts vs /src when the contents of bin/output seem to be the same in both cases

Comment: Victor also if you have an opportunity could you please look at this question I had.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977129/aspnet5-default-web-application-project-wont-run  I would appreciate any insight you might have.