# Aspnet5 default web application project won't run

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, dnx, dnx50

Why won't the "out of the box" aspnet5 web application project run with the frameworks section set to the TFM "net46" or "net451".  I can only get it to run set to "dnx451 or dnx46".  If I run it under any of the "netxx" monikers I get a connection refused in the browser instead of the aspnet splash page.

[image: working with the latest runtimes]

**UPDATE 1**
I get the following when I switch the TFM to "net46" in the project.json file so why is it still targeting the dnx 4.5.1 runtime?  Current dnvm shows as above and on another note you can switch from IISExpress to web in the droplist under the debug button right in VS2015 as well.

```
C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2>dnx web
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'WebApplication2'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   10.0
 Runtime Id:   win10-x86

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)

C:\Users\Doug\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2>dnvm list

Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
```

FYI again this is the out of the box WebApplication project for aspnet5 and here is my project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication2-59e2cf64-0111-49ef-89d6-ab19ba2a9788",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }  <--- THIS HAS TO BE DNX45,DNX451, or DNX46 for it to run
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it may depend on the version you are running.

Comment: Working with the latest run times as shown above.

Comment: Try opening a console at the project root (where project.json is located) and run `dnx web` (for weblistener). I can't debug in VS by using F5, but I can run `dnx web` without any problems. Which is very odd.

Comment: Ok I haven't tried dnu web.   I can only use the debug IISEXPRESS through visual studio when the TFM is set to one of the end targets.  Soon as I try for a net46 or other target I get an "Error connection refused" web page.  I'll try ur suggestion in a bit but if that works still curious why debug won't wouldn't work

Comment: Didn't work, see update above

Comment: Have you tried restoring your packages manually? dnu restore or right click on your project in vs and "Restore packages".

Comment: It does a restore after you change the framework in the project.json and save the file.  However I did try an additional restore packages and still no dice.