# NodeJS, how can I use 'forever start' from a batch file?

Tags: node.js

**Edit: I got it to work, but I forgot to mention that I'd like the console to remain open so I can see what's going on in real time. Is there a way to keep the console open somehow? thx!**

so my nodejs app crashes sometimes, and in order to reset it I use 'forever start index.js'

Problem is, I'm currently starting it from a .bat file and Idk how to start my app forever with the batch file

My .bat file looks like this:

"forever start index.js"

Thx for the help

"forever start index.js"

expecting my app to reset whenever it crashed

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with.  The line `forever start index.js` when run from the right current directory will start your program with `forever` and it will then auto-restart it anytime it crashes.  It doesn't matter whether that line is in a batch file or directly typed on the command line.  As long as the current directory is the same in both cases, they will work identically.  So, it's not clear what you are asking for help with.

Comment: Hi  jfriend00, that's the problem im facing right now: I'd like the console to remain open so I can see what's going on in real time. Is there a way to keep the console open somehow?

Comment: Maybe this [Batch Files: How to leave the console window open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746177/batch-files-how-to-leave-the-console-window-open/25271699).  A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+keep+console+open+from+batch+file&rlz=1C1KDEC_enUS826US826&oq=how+to+keep+console+open+from+batch+file&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4487j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows hundreds of articles on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your edit:

> Edit: I got it to work, but I forgot to mention that I'd like the console to remain open so I can see what's going on in real time. Is there a way to keep the console open somehow? thx!

Run the `bat` file from the command line, not by double-clicking on it.

You can do this by:

1. Ctrl+R -> "CMD"
2. Navigate to the folder your `bat` file is in with `cd C:/myDir/etc/`
3. Double check your `bat` file is present in the directory you have your command prompt looking at by entering `dir` and reading the output
4. Once you've found it, enter `start ./myfile.bat` and the CMD window will stay open.

Comment: So I did exactly that, and on step #4 I got this error:
https://imgur.com/a/cihrKqp

I made sure I navigated to the right directory the batch file is by using 'dir'

What am I missing here?

My bat file looks like this btw:

**forever start index.js**

Thx for your detailed comment!

Comment: Sorry, prepend `start` to your command. I'll update my answer.

Comment: well, it does open the bat file from the command line, but I don't actually see the console.log (or anything else) that my index.js produces.

Sorry for bothering you. Have been googling for like an hour trying to figure this out :/

Comment: Are you sure you should be expecting any console logging? It would appear there if so

Comment: Absolutely sure. 

When my bat file didn't have the forever in it, I'd see my index.js output in the console

Comment: Here's an example: it used to output chat messages in the console (before I added forever start in my bat file)

https://imgur.com/a/7Vecvk9